# How to fetch all rows from table if like operator value match using mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm trying to fetch all record if **like** operator value match and is true.

I have table ticket.

```
---------------------------
: id  :  ticket : user_id :
---------------------------
: 1   : 2546    : 2       :
---------------------------
: 2    : 8475    : 2      :
---------------------------
```

I'm trying this query

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE `ticket` LIKE '%2546%'
```

Above query is returning single result and is working fine. But I need both rows if **like** operator value match and table has more record of that row **user_id**. I tried group by

```
SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE `ticket` LIKE '%2546%' 
GROUP BY `user_id `
```

I know it can be done if use  `user_id = 2` instead of `like` and `Group By` operator but I need to filter by `ticket` column. So is this possible to achieve this kind of task in single query?

Comment: the first query, I mean the one without group by clause will certainly give you all the rows where your like operator matches..

Comment: @TirthrajBarot yes it is giving me records of like operator match values but i need those all if same user_id exist in other rows.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE `ticket` LIKE '%5%'  use this or  SELECT * FROM `ticket` WHERE `ticket` LIKE '%4%' this is not possible to retrieve data with  '%2546%' as it find this full string

Comment: Show us your expected output please.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `ticket` GROUP BY `user_id` ... Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I think the example is the expected input & output - ie query needs to return both rows not just the first

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a nested query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ticket t1
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT user_id
    FROM ticket t2
    WHERE ticket LIKE '%2456%'
);
```

Comment: the OP may possibly want to add _"ORDER BY user_id'"_ to ensure that all rows for a particular user are grouped together (sql gives no guarantee on the results order).

Answer (score 2):

Using self join as

```
SELECT U . * 
FROM  `ticket` t, `ticket` U
WHERE t.`ticket` LIKE  '%2546%'
AND t.`user_id` = U.`user_id`
```